# How to deal with a stale cache in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I had been getting very strange behavior form entity framework. I am coding a WebApi application so the objects I get from the browser are disconnected/detached. The data I get back is transactional such that it does not match any given table in the database. I have to do a number of lookups and data manipulation to get the actual updates to be done on the database.

The problem I seem to have is that in querying the data I am filling up the Tracked Changes cache. That wouldn't seem to be a problem to me since the true source of data should be the database. When I finally make the data changes and I call SaveChanges I get constraint errors. Here are my steps.

1. Query data.
2. Create rows to be inserted.
3. compare rows to db and make db changes.

After reviewing the data in Ctx.ChangeTracker.Entries() I found that an entry to be deleted was marked as Modified when it was supposed to be deleted. The way I worked around it was by Creating a new context for step 3. And it magically started working. I thought that was it, but in my test case I do a last read from the database to verify that my transaction was writing correctly. And I was getting an extra row that should already be deleted. And in fact was, when checking the db directly. Again a new context to do that last read fixed the problem.

I just assumed the default cache setting would just be used to track changes and not to speed up queries.

If I try to use AsNoTracking in my queries I also get into trouble because if I try to delete a row queried like that I get an error. And in my code I don't know if I am going to delete or modify until later on. Is there a way to clear the cache so I don't need to create a new context?

Is there a better way to deal with these issues?

EDIT:

AsNoTracking will do the trick, to some extent. I still found myself instantiating more copies of DbContext in order to prevent errors. Many to one entities have to be deleted in order or null foreign key errors are triggered.

```
var details = oldInvoice.details.ToList();

Context.Entry(oldInvoice).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
Context.Entry(oldInvoice).State = EntityState.Deleted;
details.ForEach(a => Context.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Deleted);
```

Comment: Its a bad idea to keep your context around for a long period of time as the tracking graph doesnt perform well when it gets a lot of entities in it. My recommendation is to not re-use your context between requests. This should also get around any concurrent updates issues

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework offers an exception `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` that you can catch on your calls to `SaveChanges()`.  you could loop through the errors something like this:

```
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        saveFailed = true;

        // Get the current entity values and the values in the database
        var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
        var currentValues = entry.CurrentValues;
        var databaseValues = entry.GetDatabaseValues();

        // Choose an initial set of resolved values. In this case we
        // make the default be the values currently in the database.
        var resolvedValues = databaseValues.Clone();

        // Have the user choose what the resolved values should be
        HaveUserResolveConcurrency(currentValues, databaseValues,
                                   resolvedValues);

        // Update the original values with the database values and
        // the current values with whatever the user choose.
        entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(databaseValues);
        entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(resolvedValues);
    }

} while (saveFailed);
```

also, your update code sounds suspicious as well.  Usually when you pass data out to a client through WebApi or other mechanisms, the data that is returned doesn't have the tracking data, so you should be checking to see if it exists and re-attaching it to the context and changing it's state to `EntityState.Modified` if so before calling `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: Andrew thanks for the answer. You are correct about the missing tracking data. So I do exactly what you describe at the bottom. Except that the previous queries mess up the tracking data.